# Add Cross-Sell/Up-sell like feature in Magento

Tags: magento

Can somebody help me with the term to use so I can do a search of the possibility to add a new cross/up-sell feature on our Store? So basically, we need to add it on the back-end and admin can choose what products are under it. For example, we want to show history of the product, so from old to latest model we will add it on the cross/up-sell-like feature.

Comment: you can use `Related Products`....

Comment: We already used related products but now, we want to show a new specific list of related products under cross-sell items in the product view page. We will name it History so products of the same origin will be there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: more suited to magento stackexchange